# Pastdate in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, datejs

I want to get past day dates(like yesterday) in knockout.
To get current date i have written like below:

```
self.currentDate = ko.observable(new Date().toString('yyyy-M-dd'))
```

But how to get date of yesterday here??

Comment: So your actual question is *"How do I subtract one day from a JavaScript date?"*, right?

Comment: yes, within an observable variable.

Comment: The original JavaScript date object does not support things like `.toString('yyyy-M-dd')`. This means you must be using a second library (besides knockout) - which one is it?

Comment: I am using Date.js for formatting. And its working in currentDate.

Comment: But date.js provides convenient methods to subtract time spans from date values. `Date.today().add(-1).day();` would be one way to do it. Maybe you should take half an hour of your time to look at [the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation). And I still don't understand where knockout comes in.

Comment: @Tomalak, actually i have tried some other methods and it was showing error for knockout. Thanks for u'r solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without testing with the date.js library, but maybe something like this could work:

```
var yesterday = Date.today().addDays(-1);
self.currentDate = ko.observable(yesterday.toString('yyyy-M-dd'));
```